# Is there a counting sketch optimized for intersections?

Tags: statistics, probability, data-stream-mining

Popular counting sketches(loglog, hyperloglog, etc) feature natural union operations. Are there any known counting sketches that feature natural intersection operations?

Comment: Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106633/best-method-to-intersect-huge-hyperloglogs-in-redis ?